# Access cygwin filesystem from host windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, cygwin

When running cygwin, it has it's internal virtual filesystem mappings which are visible to linux programs (well, ports) running inside cygwin. Accessing the host windows filesystem from within cygwin is easy, but what about the other way around? If I needed to somehow mount the virtual cygwin filesystem as a windows drive or ntfs folder or similar? Are there ready solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cygpath -w cygwin-pathname` to convert from a Cygwin path to a regular Windows path.  For example,  `cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Users` will print `C:\Users`.

Comment: Yeah but I would like to access the whole "/", not just "/cygdrive/".

Comment: The Windows equivalent to Cygwin's `/` is `C:\cygwin` with all the individual drives under the Cygwin `/cydrive` directory.  For example, `/cygdrive/c` means `C:\ `.  If you're really annoyed by the cygdrive stuff (as I would be!) perhaps you might consider my own Hamilton C shell http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm, which actually was written for Windows and understands drive letters directly.